# How to set a relation of an object of Core Data entity

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsset, database-relations

I have an entity mainEntity with three one-to-many relations to three different entities entity1, entity2 and entity3 (relations are named after objects they're referring to).

```
entity mainEntity
attribute name
relation entity1
relation entity2
relation entity3
```

These three entities have one-to-many reverse relations to this mainEntity (all the same, here's the example of first).

```
entity entity1
attribute name
relation mainEntity
```

So overall it's three many-to-many relations going from one mainEntity.

Now I need to set the three relations of mainEntity to object1, object2 and object3, which are instances of entity1, entity2 and entity3.

I can't do this:

```
MainEntity *myEntity = (MainEntity *)[NSEntityDescription
insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"myEntity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[myEntity setEntity1:object1];
[myEntity setEntity2:object2];
[myEntity setEntity3:object3];
```

Console says:
Unacceptable type of value for to-many relationship: property = "entity1"; desired type = NSSet;

How to set them properly?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you're trying to assign a single entity to a *one-to-many* relationship. If you only intended for `entity1`, `entity2`, and `entity3` to each point to a single entity at a time, the easiest (and correct) way to fix this would be to change these relationships from one-to-many to one-to-one. If, however, you *do* want each of these to be a one-to-many relationship, I would replace

```
[myEntity setEntity1:object1];
[myEntity setEntity2:object2];
[myEntity setEntity3:object3];
```

with the following automatically-generated to-many relationship mutator methods

```
[myEntity addEntity1Object:object1];
[myEntity addEntity2Object:object2];
[myEntity addEntity3Object:object3];
```

For more information, check out [Managed Object Accessor Methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdAccessorMethods.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002154-SW1) in the [*Core Data Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Comment: i.e. you told us with your words that they were to-Many relationships, you told us with your code they were to-1 relationships, - - - we're assuming your words were correct, you want multiple entity1 objects for your mainEntity

Comment: Exactly. Of course, if that's the case, I would personally rename the relations to `firstEntities`, `secondEntities`, `thirdEntities`, or some other combination that has been similarly pluralized.

Comment: You know guys, what you actually did is made me realize that I needed a one-to-many relationship not entities, but entity. Thank you. And so I did it a little otherwise.

Comment: @Mantvydas Glad to help! Would you like to share your own answer here or accept this one?